# JavaScript: Setting value using yield in nested generators

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

```
function* test(action) {
    const subgenerator = function*() {
        const subgeneratorVariable = yield '1';
        console.log('subgeneratorVariable', subgeneratorVariable);
    };

    for (const generatedValue of subgenerator()) {
        const result = yield generatedValue;
        console.log('result', result);
    }
}
const gen = test();

console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next('a'));
```

This returns:

```
{value: "1", done: false}
result a
subgeneratorVariable undefined
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

So I don't have access to yield results in the nested generator. However!

In this case:

```
function* test(action) {
    const subgenerator = function*() {
        const subgeneratorVariable = yield '1';
        console.log('subgeneratorVariable', subgeneratorVariable);
        const subgeneratorVariable2 = yield '2';
        console.log('subgeneratorVariable2', subgeneratorVariable2);
    };

    const result = yield* subgenerator();
    console.log('result', result);
}
const gen = test();

console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next('1'));
console.log(gen.next('2'));
```

The result is:

```
{value: "1", done: false}
subgeneratorVariable a
{value: "2", done: false}
subgeneratorVariable2 b
result undefined
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

So the situation is reversed. Now I have access to yielded value ONLY in nested generator.

Is there any way of passing values/results between these two generators?

Comment: I am not familiar with yield in javascript. But from a general point of view it is weird that you write instructions after your `yield` statement. Consider `yield` as a `return` that will resume execution on `.next()` call. Can you be more explicit about why you want a nested generator?

Comment: Doing `yield* subgenerator();` you delegate the generation to the sub-generator. Your generator does not resume (i.e. executes `console.log('result', result);`) until your sub-generator is finished with returning values, and ultimately returns `{value: undefined, done: true}`. It explains why you get `undefined` in the generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` is going to return what you are passing to `next` as a parameter, not the expression at right side; `for...of` internally is calling `next` without parameters so you are getting `undefined`.

Maybe this example helps you to understand with a `do...while` instead of `for...of`:

```
function* test(action) {
    const subgenerator = function*() {
        let subgeneratorVariable;

        subgeneratorVariable = yield '1';  
        console.log("subgeneratorVariable: " + subgeneratorVariable);

        subgeneratorVariable = yield '2';  
        console.log("subgeneratorVariable: " + subgeneratorVariable);
    };

    const sub = subgenerator();
    let value;        

    do {
      value = yield sub.next(value).value;
      console.log("value: " + value);
    } while(value);
}

const gen = test();
let value;

value = gen.next().value;
value = gen.next(value).value;
value = gen.next(value).value;
```

The result is:

```
value: 1
subgeneratorVariable: 1
value: 2
subgeneratorVariable: 2
```

As you can see, if you want to keep the values between the generators you must pass the result values to the generators `next` function.

Comment: I thought it can be somehow automated by generators magic, but in your example I can see that everything I was thinking about can be achieved manually, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading myself with the new `yield` in javascript and some efforts reading your examples, I think I figured out what you are trying to do and what you are doing wrong.

**Your 1st attempt was correct**. But you placed your `console.log` incorrectly which mislead you into thinking it was wrong.

I rewrote it so you get better insight of what happens when `yield`-ing.

```
function* generator() {
    function* subgenerator() {
        yield '1';
        yield '2';
    };

    for (let generatedValue of subgenerator()) {
        // Use generatedValue here ...
        console.log("Inside generator:",generatedValue);
        // .. and finally yield it to your main program
        yield generatedValue;
    }
}
let gen = generator();

console.log("Outside generator:",gen.next());
console.log("Outside generator:",gen.next());
console.log("Outside generator:",gen.next());
```

In your second example, **you delegate the generation to the subgenerator**. Doing so, you cannot get the value in your generator itself. Because the value is `yield`-ed and your generator will resume after the subgenerator is finished generating. It explains why, your generator only sees `undefined`.

Comment: This isn't it, you removed the `subgeneratorVariable` but its value is important here. If I would add it to your example it would still be undefined. :(

Comment: OK got it. So indeed you just wanted to know how to pass the yielded value back to the generator...